# How to extract all nested tar.gz and zip to a directory in PHP?

Tags: php, json, zip, tar, data-extraction

I need to extract a **tar.gz** file in **PHP**. The file contains many **JSON** files, **tar.gz**, **zip** files, and subdirectories. I need to move only the **JSON** files to a directory **./Dataset/processing** and keep extracting the nested tar.gz and zip to get all the JSON files from there. Those files could also have nested folders/ directories.

The structure is like the following:

```
origin.tar.gz
 ├───sub1.tar.gz
 │   ├───sub2.tar.gz
 │   ├───├───a.json
 │   ├───├───├───├───├───├───...(unknown depth)
 │   ├───b.json
 │   ├───c.json
 ├───sub3.zip
 │   ├───sub4.tar.gz
 │   ├───├───d.json
 │   ├───├───├───├───├───├───...(unknown depth)
 │   ├───e.json
 │   ├───f.json
 ├───subdirectory
 │   ├───g.json
 ├───h.json
 ├───i.json
 |   ..........
 |   ..........
 |   ..........
 |   many of them
```

Once it gets extracted **./Dataset** will look like this

```
Dataset/processing
 ├───a.json
 ├───b.json
 ├───c.json
 ├───d.json
 ├───e.json
 ├───f.json
 ├───g.json
 ├───h.json
 ├───i.json
 |   ..........
 |   ..........
 |   ..........
 |   many of them
```

I know how to extract a tar.gz using PharData in PHP, but it works only at a single level depth. I was thinking if some kind of recursion could make this work for multi-level depth.

```
$phar = new PharData('origin.tar.gz');
$phar->extractTo('/full/path'); // extract all files in the tar.gz
```

I have refined my code a bit and tried this, it works for multi-depth but fails when there is a directory(folder or nested folders) that also contains JSON. Can someone help me to extract them as well.

```
<?php

$path = './';

// Extraction of compressed file
function fun($path) {    
    $array = scandir($path); 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if($i == 0 OR $i == 1){continue;}
        else {
            $item = $array[$i];
            $fileExt = explode('.', $item);

            // Getting the extension of the file
            $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
            if(($fileActualExt == 'gz') or ($fileActualExt == 'zip')){
                $pathnew = $path.$item; // Dataset ./data1.tar.gz
                $phar = new PharData($pathnew);
                // Moving the files
                $phar->extractTo($path);
                // Del the files
                unlink($pathnew);
                $i=0;
            }
        }
        $array = scandir($path);


    }
}
fun($path);

// Move only the json to ./dataset(I will add it later)
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I am new to Stack Overflow. Thanks a lot for the motivation. I added the amount of research I did and my efforts towards the problem to get the desired solution. I am still suffering from an issue that  I mentioned above. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after doing a bit of research. This solves the problem.

There are 3 functions:

- recursiveScanProtected(): It extracts all the Compressed files
- scanJSON(): It will scan for JSON files and move them to the processing folder.
- delete_files(): This function removes everything except the processing folder where have the JSON files, and index.php in the root directory.

```
<?php

// Root directory
$path = './';

// Directory where I want to extract the JSON files
$path_json = $path.'processing/';


// Function to extract all the compressed files
function recursiveScanProtected($dir, $conn) {
    if($dir != '') {
        $tree = glob(rtrim($dir, '/') . '/*');
        if (is_array($tree)) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($tree); $i++) {
                $file = $tree[$i];
                if (is_dir($file)) {
                    recursiveScanProtected($file, $conn); // Recursive call if directory
                } elseif (is_file($file)) {

                    $item = $file;
                    $fileExt = explode('.', $item); 
                    // Getting the extension of the file
                    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
                    // Check if the file is a zip or a tar.gz
                    if(($fileActualExt == 'gz') or ($fileActualExt == 'zip')){

                        // Moving the file - Overwriting true
                        $phar->extractTo($dir.$i."/", null, true);

                        // Del the compressed file
                        unlink($item);

                        recursiveScanProtected($dir.$i, $conn); // Recursive call
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
recursiveScanProtected($path, $conn);


// Move the JSON files to processing
function scanJSON($dir, $path_json) {
    if($dir != '') {
        $tree = glob(rtrim($dir, '/') . '/*');
        if (is_array($tree)) {
            foreach($tree as $file) {
                if (is_dir($file)) {
                    // Do not scan processing recursively, but all other directories should be scanned
                    if($file != './processing'){
                        scanJSON($file, $path_json);
                    }
                } elseif (is_file($file)) {

                    $ext = pathinfo($file);

                    if(strtolower($ext['extension']) == 'json'){
                        // Move the JSON files to processing
                        rename($file, $path_json.$ext['basename']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

scanJSON($path, $path_json);

/* 
 * php delete function that deals with directories recursively
 * It deletes everything except ./dataset/processing and index.php
 */
function delete_files($target) {

    if(is_dir($target)){
        $files = glob( $target . '*', GLOB_MARK ); //GLOB_MARK adds a slash to directories returned
        foreach( $files as $file ){
            if($file == './processing/' || $file == './index.php'){
                continue;
            } else{
                delete_files( $file );
            }
        }
        if($target != './'){
            rmdir( $target );
        }
    } elseif(is_file($target)) {
        unlink( $target );  
    }
}

delete_files($path);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the very first step, extract your tar.gz file like u mentioned:

```
$phar = new PharData('origin.tar.gz');
$phar->extractTo('/full/path'); // extract all files in the tar.gz
```

Then read the directory recursively, move all json type files into your destination directory, and here is my code with annotation:

```
$dirPath='./';       // the root path of your very first extraction of your tar.gz

recursion_readdir($dirPath,1);


function recursion_readdir($dirPath,$Deep=0){
    $resDir=opendir($dirPath);
    while($basename=readdir($resDir)){
        //current file path
        $path=$dirPath.'/'.$basename;
        if(is_dir($path) AND $basename!='.' AND $basename!='..'){
            //it is directory, then go deeper
            $Deep++;//depth+1
            recursion_readdir($path,$Deep);
        }else if(basename($path)!='.' AND basename($path)!='..'){
            //it is not directory,
            //when the file is json file
                if(strstr($basename,'json')) {
                        //copy the file to your destination path
                    copy($path, './dest/' . $basename);

            } else if(strstr($basename,'tar')){
                //when the file is tar.gz file, extract this tar.gz file
                $phar = new PharData($basename);
                $phar->extractTo($dirPath, null, true);
            }
        }

    }
    closedir($resDir);
}
function forChar($char='-',$times=0){
  $result='';
  for($i=0;$i<$times;$i++){
     $result.=$char;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort and time, but it does not work if there are a few directories (folders that also contain JSON files). I have also shown my approach. I would be grateful if you could help me out.